# Spin statistical theorem in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, special-relativity, particle-physics, spin-statistics

In Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem?wprov=sfti1

It states that

> “The proof requires the following assumptions:
>
> 1. The theory has a Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian.
> 2. The vacuum is Lorentz-invariant.
> 3. The particle is a localized excitation. Microscopically, it is not attached to a string or domain wall.
> 4. The particle is propagating, meaning that it has a finite, not infinite, mass.
> 5. The particle is a real excitation, meaning that states containing this particle have a positive-definite norm.”

So the question is Whether there is a generalization of it in curved spacetime？

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is such a book about this generalization of spin statistics in curved spacetime:

> The connection between spin and statistics is examined in
>   the context of locally covariant quantum field theory. A gene
>   ralization
>   is proposed in which locally covariant theories are defined a
>   s functors
>   from a category of framed spacetimes to a category of
>   ∗
>   -algebras. This
>   allows for a more operational description of theories with s
>   pin, and for
>   the derivation of a more general version of the spin-statist
>   ics connection
>   in curved spacetimes than previously available. The proof i
>   nvolves a
>   “rigidity argument” that is also applied in the standard set
>   ting of locally
>   covariant quantum field theory to show how properties such as
>   Einstein
>   causality can be transferred from Minkowski spacetime to ge
>   neral curved
>   spacetimes.

Please see the citation here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05797.pdf